# Momentum and Kaluza-Klein charge

Tags: general-relativity, kaluza-klein

In normal Kaluza Klein reduction over a $S^1$, the momentum round the circle contributes to the electric charge in the lower dimensional theory.

I am curious as to whether, under certain circumstances (e.g. if background spacetime isn't asymptotically flat or something like this), is it possible for something besides the momentum to also contribute to this charge? For example, if there was a black hole present, could some property of the black hole also affect the resulting lower dimensional charge?